# На чем лучше писать сайт?

Tags: cms

Логистика.

**Цель проекта:** догружать наши машины грузом сторонних контрагентов, с последующей разгрузкой в торговых точках по маршруту следования.

**Цель сайта:** предоставить контрагентам возможность выбора маршрута и оформления заявки на перевозку.

Структура данных будет продиктована 1С- разработчиками. Работа в 1С первична: расписание маршрутов, объём свободного места в машине на маршруте - определяются сервером 1С. На плечи сайта ложится управление авторизацией пользователей, калькуляция для пользователя стоимости отправки по маршрутам заданного количества продукции, доступ в личный кабинет с историей заявок.

***Не могу определиться, какая cms лучше или все-таки писать вручную. Прошу совета знатоков***

Comment: Капитан очевидность, тут. Делать на том что умеешь

Comment: @pwnz Я мало работал с платформами, так что в любом случае придется изучать много. Я спрашиваю, на какой будет проще всего выполнить задачу?

Comment: Проще всего под задачи 1C использовать crm Bitrix24. Но тут дело вкуса))